# How to dynamicaly insert a PartialView and then will be able to update it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I'm dynamically inserting PartialViews like this:

```
if(condition)
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load(@Url.Content("/Controller/DoOneThing");
else
    $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("/Controller/DoAnotherThing");
```

But I'm not able to update them after inserting like I could be able using `Html.Action()`

So how could I insert them dynamically and still be able to update them?

Comment: What do you mean _still be able to update them_? And what would be the difference using `Html.Action()`?

Comment: @Stephen If I'll try to update the PartialView after using load() method, it will return only PartialView, without the rest of the page. There is no such problem using Html.Action(), but I don't how to use it dynamically depending on a condition, insert it in particular place.

Comment: But why would you want _the rest of the page_? The `.load()` method is an ajax call so you stay on the same page (you don't need to update the rest of it) . And `Html.Action()` is a sever side method and is only called when you first generate the view. I don't understand what it is that your trying to do.

Comment: @Stephen No, you see, I've used the .load() method it worked as a charm. But then if I will try to update the PartitialView(call return PartialView()) I get on only that PartitialView and nothing else and loose the rest of the page,

Comment: What do you mean lose the rest of the page? That makes no sense. And how are you triggering the `.load()` functions - show the full jquery code.

Comment: @Stephen load.() method works just fine, I call it on $(document).ready.() method. It loads the PartialView just as I want, but then when I want to update it I call return PartialView() and all I've got is that PrtitailView without the rest of the page. I wouldn't have such problem using Html.Action() but I don't how to use it in this case.

Comment: Sorry, but your not making any sense. Why would you do that in `$(document).ready()` as opposed to `Html.Action()`? And what is the code you are using to update it (`return PartialView();` is the server side, not client side code - you need to show the script)

Comment: @Stephen Ok, let me tell you what exactly I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to dynamically insert one of PrtialViews depending on user's input so I do it via JS in $(document).ready(). Once I've load it the user is able to input some information in it, in case if the information is invalid I want to return that View back, maybe I should check the information via JavaScript?

Comment: I assume then that you partials contain forms which your posting to a controller method? You need to edit your question with more information including the controller method. And how are you submitting the form (a normal submit or using ajax?)

Comment: @Stephen Yeah, it's a normal submitting. Controller is checking Model.State if it's good it returns another PartialView otherwise returns the same back. Do you want me to add this information to the question didn't think it is relevant.

Comment: Yes its relevant. You will need to use ajax to post the form if you want to stay on the same page (I recently added [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32850992/display-mvc-partial-view-with-errors-on-parent-page/32939702#32939702) which might help explain). But I suspect the real problem is your desig,n and that you should have one form/one submit/one controller rather that conditionally generating forms.

Comment: As a side note, instead of `@Url.Content("/Controller/DoOneThing")`, do this: `@Url.Action("DoOneThing", "Controller")`.